# Проблема с WEOF

Tags: c, ввод

Недавно скомпилировал программу на виртуальной машине. ОС - linux. И возникла проблема с распознаванием конечного символа. Вот упрощенный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    wchar_t current_symbol;
    while ((current_symbol = getwchar()) != WEOF){
        ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Программа никогда не заканчивает свое действие. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `getwchar()` возвращает

```
wint_t getwchar();
```

Так что ваш `current_symbol` никак не может стать равным `WEOF`. Объявите его как `wint_t`.

Точно так же, как и `getchar` возвращает `int`, а не `char` - о чем с завидной регулярностью все забывают...

Да, надеюсь, вы закрываете входящий поток? Чем там в Linux - Ctrl-D, кажется?

Comment: объявление как wint_t почему то не помогло

Comment: Вы закрыли входящий поток? `WEOF` означает, что вы закончили работу с потоком и закрыли его (в Windows - ввели Ctrl-Z, в Linux, если не ошибаюсь, Ctrl-D).

Comment: пытаюсь понять как это сделать

Comment: @Python_beginner нет, цикл выполняется пока выполняется его условие. Так что пока не обнаружит `WEOF` будет выполняться.

Comment: Запишите текст в файл и передавайте типа `./a.out < textfile` - по окончании чтения поток завершится и вы увидите завершение цикла.